# Visual studio - access excel interop dll file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to update an Excel interop dll file, since it changed with the new version of visual studio. But when I add the reference, I can't access the path that the dll is saved to. Is there a way to control the path that the dll file goes to?

Comment: Not sure of you requirements but you may want to take a look at the EPPlus library (http://epplus.codeplex.com/) especially if you aren't sure if the machine that is running your code will have Excell installed.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL is never actually "saved" anywhere, assuming you added the reference like this...

[image]

That interop assembly should just exist already on your hard drive (Visual Studio does not need to generate it). So assuming that is the way you added the reference then...

1. Expand the references of the project and select the interop reference then note the location reported in the **Path** property of the Properties view (the property is read-only by design).
2. In Windows, navigate to the location obtained above and copy the interop DLL to the location you desire to truly reference it from.
3. Remove the originally added reference from the project references and re-add it only this time choose the **Browse** option and simply browse to the DLL you copied in the new location rather than adding it from the **Extensions** tab in the Reference Manager dialog.

Now your project will look for the DLL in the location you browsed to instead of the one in the default location.

Comment: You're welcome, please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)